# Java Number Exception at string input from buffereader

Tags: java, visual-studio, exception, numberformatexception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Ex
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
     {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a,b,n,c;
        n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
        {   
            try
            { 
                a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                try
                {
                    c=a/b;
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
                catch (ArithmeticException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } 
            }    
            catch (InputMismatchException m) 
            {
                System.out.println(m);
            }       
        } 
    }
}
```

The above mentioned is my Code which I'm trying to run 
and below is the input_file.txt

```
4 
10
3
10
Hello
10
2
23.323
0.0
```

and this is the error which I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 "
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at Ex.main(Ex.java:11)
```

Comment: The exception told you already. It is because there is an extraneous space in your string `"4 "`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have entered the number 4 with space. Please check your input.

For input string: **"4 "**

To avoid it you can add trim function as below

```
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 "
```

As you can see from the error message above the String you are trying to parse as a number has a space at the end which will cause the parsing to fail.

To get rid of leading and trailing spaces you can use the [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) method on Strings:

```
a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```